# How to passing Text Input value from Gallery Control as a json in Power Apps?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, power-automate

I try to create power apps for dynamics.
The main issue is changing the amount value in all list and then send the web API via power automate.

Hence, I create a flow in 'Power Automate' and Create a canvas 'Power App'. The power app is already connected to a data source. I add a 'Text Input' to enter the new value.

But I can't pass the Text Inputs value from the list. I need all 'TextInput' values from the gallery as a JSON.

Here is my code belong to action button

```
HttpPostTest.Run(JSON(BrowseGallery1.AllItems.'Routing number'));
```

I also add my screenshots.

Power App :

[image]

Power Automate :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the items in the gallery, you need to use ForAll. Something like:

```
 Notify(JSON(ForAll(BrowseGallery1.AllItems, { MyVal : TextInput3.Text })))
```

JSON() will not automatically iterate of the gallery.

You can use Notify(JSon(...))  to help debug this and see the json payloads you're generating before making the http post.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. It is worked. Finding documents is really hard about power apps.