# Powerapps : Pass a json Array to a Flow

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

**Context**

I'm currently working on a specific search engine frontend, based on Powerapps, which need to pass a string array to a service through a Power-Automate Flow, in order to specify a filter.

**The Flow**

The flow itself takes a JSON object as input (which will be transmitted to the backend service), which looks something like this :

```
{
    service: "string"
    types : ["A", "B", "C", ...]
}
```

But Powerapps do not allow to create arrays, according to multiple source I found.
When I try to serialize my object trough the JSON() function, I end up with the following result:

```
{
    service: "string"
    types : [{"Value" : "A"}, {"Value" : "B"}, {"Value" : "C"}, ...]
}
```

I've tried the following ways (and some more but I don't remember them all) to generate the object, hopping for something working, but I'm now out of idea.

`Collect(arrayTypes; ["A", "B", "C", ...])`
`ClearCollect(arrayTypes; ["A", "B", "C", ...])`
`Set(arrayTypes; ["A", "B", "C", ...])`
`Set(arrayTypes; JSON(["A", "B", "C", ...]))`
`Set(arrayTypes; JSON(["A", "B", "C", ...].Value))`
`JSON(ForAll(arrayTypes.Value; ThisRecord.Value))`

I'm currently considering passing the array as a comma separated string, and then insert it as a new value inside the JSON, but this will require to change the Power-Automate flow quite substantially (we actually got multiple array to pass), and I would prefer not to change this part too much.

Does anyone know a way to generate a proper JSON array from a Powerapps Collection/Table/Variable ?

**Similar questions on StackOverflow that I've found**
[Nested tables in Powerapps - remove “Value” column when parsing JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68375987/nested-tables-in-powerapps-remove-value-column-when-parsing-json) (No answer)
[How to passing Text Input value from Gallery Control as a json in Power Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63725353/how-to-passing-text-input-value-from-gallery-control-as-a-json-in-power-apps) (Answer did not change anything to the current output)